# Why the result not fit when I run group by and order by?

Tags: mysql

My query like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM products_categories
WHERE product_id = 1
ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

If the query run, the result like this :

[image]

I add group by like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM products_categories
WHERE product_id = 1
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

The result : display 1 record (id=1)

It does not fit. Should the id shown is id = 3 (latest updated_at)

How can I solve it?

Comment: The idea behind group by is to group multiple records together in one result per value (or values) in the group by clause. Since you don't have any aggregating functions on the other fields (Like sum, max, group_concat, etc.), it will display values from one of the rows in the group.

Comment: The order by is applied after the grouping, so the value you get isn't determined by the order by in your case.

Comment: With `GROUP BY` `ORDER BY` doesn't work as normally it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are trapped by the strange behavior of mysql (some other sql engines like sqlite do the same). Your sql query is not correct according to sql98 and should be yield an error. You can not select fields which are not grouped for or using aggregate function (max/min/avg). Unfortunately mysql wont yield an error but gives back the first value for the ill defined fields.

The group by will *merge* all your rows with the same product_id into single row. That's why you get 1 (wrong) line back.  I suppose you thought the order by will run first before the group by. This is not the case. The single (grouped by) row will be sorted.

If you want to get the latest updated_at, you should query that:
select max(updated_at) from products_categories WHERE product_id = 1 and then query the row which using this value in an another select. (select * from products_categories where product_id=1 and updated_at = (select max(updated_at) from products_categories where products_id=1)) Of course it may not work as intended if your updated_at value is not unique. Then you will get multiple results.

If you need strictly one answer row you can do 
SELECT * FROM products_categories
WHERE product_id = 1  ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 1;